# In Symfony, how to export to csv using YAML?

Tags: symfony1, admin, yaml

How can I provide `export to csv` facility in generator.yml using Symfony 1.4?

Comment: My understanding is that it cannot be done with 1.4. I have to write code myself by getting it from cache directory. Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

You should use the batch actions to do this.